# Extracting specific text from a file in java

Tags: java, io

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.LineNumberReader;

public class ReadingfromModellerOutput {

    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
    {
       // BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("ModellerOutput.txt"));
      LineNumberReader reader=  new LineNumberReader(new FileReader("ModellerOutput1.txt"));

        String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
           if(line.startsWith("Summary"))
           {

            System.out.println(reader.getLineNumber());
             for(int i=reader.getLineNumber();i<=(reader.getLineNumber()+50);i++)
            {
               System.out.println(reader.getLineNumber());
                writeTofile(line);
            }   

             }
             }
           }
    public static void writeTofile(String line)
    {
        //System.out.println(reader.getLineNumber());
          //   for(int i=reader.getLineNumber();i<=(reader.getLineNumber()+50);i++)
           //  {
                 // System.out.println(reader.getLineNumber());
          try 
              {
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("Output_1.txt"), true));
            System.out.println("Hi");
            bw.write(line);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
    }

    }
```

I am trying to write a code to extract 50 lines from a text file following the line which starts with 
**Summary of the restraint violations:** 
The above code is writing the same line **Summary of the restraint violations:** 50 times. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

```
System.out.println(reader.getLineNumber());
line = reader.readLine(); // You forgot to put this.
writeTofile(line);
```

Also do not forget to put a `break;` after your `for` loop(within the `if`), so that you don't end up writing more lines post your `50 lines`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be reading lines inside the for loop.

But you must then check again for end of file. Look at this implementation:

```
String line = reader.readLine();
while (line != null) {
    if (line.startsWith("Summary")) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            line = reader.readLine();
            if (line != null) {
                writeTofile(line);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
line = reader.readLine();
```

Above line should have been inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this program.  With proper Break statements

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.LineNumberReader;

public class ReadingfromModellerOutput {

    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
    {
       // BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("ModellerOutput.txt"));
      LineNumberReader reader=  new LineNumberReader(new FileReader("ModellerOutput1.txt"));

        String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
           if(line.startsWith("Summary"))
           {

            System.out.println(reader.getLineNumber());
             for(int i=reader.getLineNumber();i<=(reader.getLineNumber()+50);i++)
            {
               System.out.println(reader.getLineNumber());
                writeTofile(line);
            }   
             break;
             }
             }
           }
    public static void writeTofile(String line)
    {
        //System.out.println(reader.getLineNumber());
          //   for(int i=reader.getLineNumber();i<=(reader.getLineNumber()+50);i++)
           //  {
                 // System.out.println(reader.getLineNumber());
          try 
              {
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("Output_1.txt"), true));
            System.out.println("Hi");
            bw.write(line);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
    }

    }
```